# Push array from backend to vuex store not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, quasar-framework, quasar

Errors:  Error in created hook (Promise/async): "TypeError: state.push is not a function"
TypeError: state.push is not a function

Method in page

`created: async function () {   this.$store.commit('TicketSystem/ADD_BOARDS', (await this.$axios.get('https://localhost:7166/boards')).data) }`

mutation method

`export function ADD_BOARDS (state, payload) { state.push(payload) }`

Object

```
[{"id":1,"name":"string"}]
```

I build Backend in .NET and Frontend in Quasar and now I am trying connect them. I created Page, Method on created and mutation method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that state is an object, not an array. But you can add an array property to the state and store your data there:

```js
{
  state: {
    boards: []
  },

  mutations: {
    ADD_BOARDS (state, payload) { 
      state.boards.push(payload) 
    }
  }
}
```